# 2018 USGS Geospatial PDF produces `ERROR 1: insufficient arguments for Marked Content`

Tags: gdal-translate, geospatial-pdf

#### Issue

When processing the 2018 Geospatial PDFs from the [nationalMap.gov](http://nationalMap.gov) an error occurs that was not seen when processing the same quadrangle from 2015.

*I should note:  there is **no** problem with `gdal_translate`, but an extra noisy ERROR that wasn't in previous versions of the GeospatialPDF*

- **What** — Processing USGS US Topos from 2018 with `gdal_translate`
- **Error** — produces `ERROR 1: insufficient arguments for Marked Content`
- **Compare** — 2015 USGS US Topo does not produce this same error
- **Compute time** — the 2015 US Topo also takes less time complete in GDAL compared to 2018's version

#### Steps to reproduce

GDAL translate produces a TIFF as expected.

2015 GeospatialPDF

```
# wget
wget 
https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Maps/USTopo/PDF/CA/CA_Descanso_20150223_TM_geo.pdf

#gdal
gdal_translate CA_Descanso_20150223_TM_geo.pdf CA_Descanso_20150223_TM_geo.tif -co COMPRESS=LZW --config GDAL_PDF_DPI 200
```

2018 GeospatialPDF

```
# wget 
wget 
https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Maps/USTopo/PDF/CA/CA_Descanso_20180904_TM_geo.pdf

#gdal
gdal_translate CA_Descanso_20180904_TM_geo.pdf CA_Descanso_20180904_TM_geo.tif -co COMPRESS=LZW --config GDAL_PDF_DPI 200

# Errors many times; similar to this
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918296, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918296, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918317, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918327, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918327, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918329, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918334, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918334, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918334, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918339, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47918343, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47920226, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47920231, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47920268, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47920268, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47920271, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47946009, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47946015, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47947917, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
ERROR 1: Pos = 47954326, insufficient arguments for Marked Content
```

Comment: Related thread on `transdem.de`, titled *Problem Opening USGS 2018 Topo Maps* — https://forum.transdem.de/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=546