# 2018 USGS US Topo Render Differently in Browsers

Tags: pdf, geospatial-pdf, browser

While opening in a browser a 2018 Geospatial PDF from the USGS, I noticed that different PDF browsers open the same file differently.  I'm looking for a clue as to why they are different.

#### Compare

When comparing the same Geospatial PDF in four browsers on macOS Mojave (macOS 10.14.3 (18D42)) —

- Chrome & Opera show only the most basic vector layers (contours, roads, etc)
- Safari & Firefox shows contours, roads, etc, but also shows the `Orthoimage` base layer.  The Preview app on macOS Mojave also behaves like Safari and shows the `Orthoimage`.

#### Issue

I am not certain which browser is right.  These are the scenarios that could be happening:

1. Chrome and Opera use the same PDF renderer; read the Geospatial PDF and decide to not show the `Orthoimage` layer, or
2. Firefox and Safari use strong rendering standards, and the Geospatial PDF does not give that proper directive, or
3. The issue is related to [2018 USGS Geospatial PDF produces `ERROR 1: insufficient arguments for Marked Content`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/309193), or
4. Your guess is good as mine. BTW, the USGS PDFs are excellent and my hats off to them for refreshing the US Topo products.

#### Steps to Reproduce

For example, if I obtain this 2018 Geospatial PDF from the [NationalMap.gov](http://NationalMap.gov)

```
 wget https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Maps/USTopo/PDF/CA/CA_Descanso_20180904_TM_geo.pdf
```

And I open it on the browsers I have on macOS (Chrome, Safari, Opera, FireFox), I get the rendering of each in the image below.  Safari & macOS Preview  & Firefox both show the Orthoimage layer.

[image: browsers]

---

#### Edit

I have found that a National Park Service Geospatial PDF for Joshua Tree has a similar issue. **This again leads me to believe its how the PDF renderer for these browsers behaves differently.**

Steps to reproduce Joshua Tree, where the Shaded Relief layer does not show in macOS Preview.

```
wget  https://www.nps.gov/carto/hfc/carto/media/JOTRmap1.pdf
```

[image: NPS Geospatial PDF that exhibits the same problem]